# How do I eager load the latest record where each record have a different value of a certain column?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say I have this table called **messages**

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| ID | user_id      | conv_id     |body |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|1..5|            1 |           1 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 6  |            1 |           3 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|  7 |            1 |           3 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|  8 |            1 |           1 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|  9 |            1 |           2 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 10 |            1 |           1 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 11 |            1 |           2 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+ 
| 12 |            1 |           4 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 13 |            1 |           5 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 14 |            1 |           4 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

And I want to output this result :

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|2..5|            1 |           1 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 10 |            1 |           1 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
|  7 |            1 |           3 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 11 |            1 |           2 | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 13 |            1 |           5 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 14 |            1 |           4 |...  |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

as the result of eager loading. As you can see, it outputs 5 latest record where `conv_id = 1` **plus the most recent record of each of every other `conv_id`**. How do I do that?

---

**This is my controller code and what I've tried**

```
$loginuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

//$allOpenConvMsgs is an array of 5 message IDs where `conv_id = 1`.
//The relationship between user and messages is many-to-many. 
  See model codes below

$newMessages = $loginuser->messages()->where(function($q){
                   $q->where(''); //I'm stuck here!
               })->orWhereIn('messages.id',$allOpenConvMsgs);
```

**Messages model**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

**User model**

```
public function messages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Messages');
}
```

Comment: Can't you add one more field `message_datetime`? and then you can just `order by message_datetime desc`

Comment: Just a note: `Auth::user()` returns a user model for the logged in user. Taking it's id and querying for it again is pointless, just use it as it is.

Comment: @Log1cツ I'd rather use the ID based on past experience of using time-based solutions-some messages might go missing during retrieving. Even so, most importantly, I need the latest message of every `conv_id`

Answer (score 1):

If I get your point, you can do something like this:

```
$loginuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->with(array('messages' => function($q){
    $q->where('conv_id', '=', '1')->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
})->get();

$newMessages = $loginuser->messages;
```

**Update**

After David's suggestion it will be better to use already fetched `User` instance by `Auth::user()` function.

So the above code will be:

```
$newMessages = Auth::user()->load(array('messages' => function($q){
        $q->where('conv_id', '=', '1')->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }))->messages;
```

**Update 2**

The above code only gets the messages with `conv_id = 1`, to get all recent messages you have to remove `where` condition:

```
$newMessages = Auth::user()->load(array('messages' => function($q){
            $q->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        }))->messages;
```

Comment: or just `Auth::user()->load(array('messages' => function($q) { ... });`

Comment: @DavidBarker then after `load` I use `get` as usual?

Comment: No, the user model is already fetched in the return of `Auth::user()`. That's why we use `load`, not `with` to lazy eager load messages onto an existing model. In the return value of `load()` you don't have an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` so calling get will throw an exception. I believe an instance of the model is returned with its relationship loaded.

Comment: @DavidBarker so the result after load will be messages collection?

Comment: No, the result after `load()` will be a user model with its relationships loaded, `$user->messages` will return a collection.

Comment: @MohammadWalid your code only gets the latest 5 messages from conv_id = 1. However, I also need the most recent message of every other `conv_id` where `conv_id != 1`. see the expected output in the question again. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark it's pretty simple to do it see the update please.

Comment: @MohammadWalid thanks but sorry if I've not been clear enough. It seems that it loads only the latest 5 of the **total messages from all conversations** regardless of whether it is `conv_id =1` or not. What I need is 5 latest messages of `conv_id = 1` **AND** a most recent message **each from every other `conv_id`**. I have expanded my example above. Have a look, thanks! You can see from the example that I have 5 latest messages from `conv_id = 1` and 1 most recent message **each** from `conv_id =2,3,4 and 5` respectively